# Grunt jade compiles and merges multiple jade files into single html

Tags: pug, gruntjs

**Yeoman / grunt / jade**

I have folder structure like :

```
App/
App/jade/user.jade
        /user.edit.jade
        /user.details.jade
```

when jade complies the files it creates single html file as (**App/user.html**) for all the three seperate files.

I need it as all three seperate files as :

```
App/user.html
   /user.edit.html
   /user.details.html
```

My grunt configuration is as below :

```
    jade: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                pretty: true
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/jade',
                    src: '{,*/}*.jade',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.app %>/',
                    ext: '.html'             
                  }]                
              }
    },
```

Am i missing out something? please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how it compiles the `user.html` at all seeing as the `files` array shouldn't be inside `options`. The `files` array looks correct though.

Answer (score 0):

This configuration is working for me:

```
jade: {
  dist: {
    options: { pretty: true }
    files: [
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'jade',
      src: [ '**/*.jade' ],
      dest: 'app',
      ext: '.html'
    ]
  }
}
```